# Android KeyStore setKeyEnty throws NPE on String.length

Tags: android, bouncycastle, keystore

I have problem with creating `KeyStore` with client certificate for authentication. As you can see the exception comming from BounceCastle, so I am unable to debug the `BcKeyStoreSpi.engineSetKeyEntry`. I have no idea what String is null. All my parameters are filled and seems correct. What is wrong with my solution?

I am able to reproduce this on multiple devices (Android 9, 8.1, 7.0). Also I have already tried to disable proguard but still it is throwing the NPE. Even multiple certificates.

Code

```
String certAlias = "alias";
PrivateKey privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(context, certAlias);
X509Certificate[] certChain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(context, certAlias);
X509Certificate mdmCert = certChain[0];

char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
String alis = "private";
HeldCertificate heldCertificate = new HeldCertificate(
        new KeyPair(
                mdmCert.getPublicKey(),
                privateKey
        ),
        mdmCert
);
X509Certificate[] certificates = new X509Certificate[certChain.length + 1];
certificates[0] = heldCertificate.certificate();
System.arraycopy(certChain, 0, certificates, 1, certChain.length);


KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null, password);
ks.setKeyEntry(             //this is the problematic part
        alis,
        heldCertificate.keyPair().getPrivate(),
        password,
        certificates

);
```

Stacktrace

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.leng
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineSetKeyEntry(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:685)
    at java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1179)
    at cz.kctdata.skoenergo.ui.activity.MainActivity$GetCertAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:153)
    at cz.kctdata.skoenergo.ui.activity.MainActivity$GetCertAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:86)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```